# Having trouble saving NSMutable dictionary to documents. UIImage won't save/display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdata

I have a sticker class and I am saving sticker objects to a NSMutableDictionary. Sticker class below:

```
#import "Sticker.h"

@implementation Sticker


-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title stickerNO:(int)stickerNO image:(UIImage *)image {



    self=[super init];
    if(self){

        self.title=title;
        self.stickerNO=[NSNumber numberWithInt:stickerNO];;
        self.image=image;
    }


    return  self;

}


//CODING METHODS//////////////


-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{

    //choose what we save, these are objects
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.stickerNO forKey:@"stickerNO"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.image forKey:@"image"];


}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        self.title=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.stickerNO=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"stickerNO"];
        self.image=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"];
    }

    return self;



}

@end
```

The dictionary is managed by the class StickerManager:

```
@implementation StickerManager


-(instancetype)init {

    self = [super init];

    //load the dictionary
    NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
    self.stickerDictionary=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    //if there is no dictionary create it and add the default
    if(!self.stickerDictionary) {

        NSLog(@"Creating dictionary and adding default");
        self.stickerDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [self addDefaultStickers];
        [self saveStickerDictionary];

    }
    //if empty fill it
    else if ([self.stickerDictionary count]==0){
        NSLog(@"Dictionary exists but it empty");
        [self addDefaultStickers];
        [self saveStickerDictionary];

    }


    return self;


}


//add the stickers included in the app bundle
-(void)addDefaultStickers {

    Sticker *sticker = [[Sticker alloc] initWithTitle:@“Batman” stickerNO:1 image:[UIImage imageNamed:@“batman.png"]];

    [self.stickerDictionary setObject:sticker forKey:sticker.title];



}


-(BOOL)saveStickerDictionary{

    NSLog(@"Saving stickers");
    //get the path from above
    NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];

    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.stickerDictionary toFile:path];
}



-(NSString *)itemArchivePath
{

   //get the directory
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   //set it to a string
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];


    //here we call the file items.archive
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stickers.archive"];

}



@end
```

If when the StickerManager is init if it is empty or doesn't exist it will create and fill the dictionary with the default stickers by calling addDefaultStickers. This is working for the one sticker I have in the code. I can load and restore the dictionary and use NSLog to check the contents. The sticker is there but for some reason the UIImage is null and I can't display it. I'm really not sure why, I have used the encodeWithCoder for it so shouldn't it work? The odd thing is that if I download a sticker from Parse.com (I have an identical class on it) and then convert that image from NSData to png and save it will work. Could someone give me some pointers please to what might be going wrong here? Thanks

EDIT This is my download from Parse.com code:

```
- (void)getNewStickersWithCompletionHandler:(stickerCompletionHandler)handler
{


    __weak StickerManager *weakSelf = self;
    PFQuery *stickersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"sticker"];

    [stickersQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {



            for( PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSString *title = object[@"title"];
                int stickerNO = [[object objectForKey:@"stickerNO"] intValue];


                //DOWNLOAD IMAGE CODE
                PFFile *image = object[@"image"];
                [image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                    if(!error){

                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        Sticker *sticker = [[Sticker alloc] initWithTitle:title stickerNO:stickerNO image:image];

                        [weakSelf.stickerDictionary setObject:sticker forKey:sticker.title];
                        [self saveStickerDictionary];
                        handler(YES,nil);

                    }

                }];//end get image block




            }//end for






        }
    }];//end download stickers block


}
```

If I save a sticker to the dictionary this way there are no issues and I can display the image. This is almost identical to the addDefaultStickers, I am saving a UIImage and not saving the NSData. No Idea what is up here..

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a well constructed question and the answer is not obvious at all.

Comment: OP: I assume `Sticker` declares that it conforms to `NSCoding`? (I am not certain if the dictionary will test its members using `conformsToProtocol` or if they implement the protocol methods).

Comment: yes it conforms to NSCoding

Comment: @trojanfoe added my download code, if the sticker is downloaded the image will display...but I'm not really doing anything differently...

Comment: OK add a breakpoint in the `[Sticker init..]` method and check that `image` is correct.

Comment: yup, it has a pointer to a UIImage. Is the problem that I need to store images as NSData?

Comment: @KeXMeX, Yes, UIImage is not a valid plist type. You need to convert it to NSData before saving. AFAIK Parse should say this in error too.

Comment: Ah yes; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962226/how-to-encode-a-uiimage-in-an-nscoder)

Comment: That's what is odd, why does it it work for the images I got from Parse?

Comment: Because you get PFFile from Parse, not UIImage. And then you get data and UIImage from it. That's why you can display image if it's from Parse. UIImage is simply not nil in that case.

Comment: @KeXMeX , probably you should then post an answer and accept it(you can do it), just for future reference.

Comment: @TimurKuchkarov done. cheers

Answer (score 1):

just for other people's reference the problem was in not first converting the UIImage to NSData. I changed UIImage lines in the aCoder method to below:

```
[aCoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) forKey:@"image"];
```

and in the aDecoder: `self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"image"]];`

don't totally understand why it was working for NSData that was converted to a UIImage for the Parse download before but it's all working now anyway.